# Set up SDL2 on Mac Clion or XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, sdl, sdl-2, clion

I was trying to set up SDL2 on Mac Clion and XCode and both have occurred some problems. This is what I got from XCode:

```
2020-07-16 23:42:59.224392-0700 Trying_See_if_SDL2_Works[78612:8627338] Metal API Validation Enabled

2020-07-16 23:42:59.287864-0700 Trying_See_if_SDL2_Works[78612:8628129] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35

2020-07-16 23:42:59.288955-0700 Trying_See_if_SDL2_Works[78612:8628129] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

And this is the code I used for testing: (C++)

```
#include "/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/SDL.h"

#include <iostream>

int main() {

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)!=0){

        std::cout<<"SDL Init Error: "<<SDL_GetError();

        return 1;

}

  SDL_Quit();

  return 0;

}
```

Can anyone give some advice on how to set up frameworks properly on Clion?

Comment: Those warnings seem harmless. Since you received error code 0, your program reached the end. Try one of the example SDL2 programs that actually show something.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The only answer I see on every forum is "restart and clear the cache" but it doesn't work. Also @Botje while the program reaches the end it won't do almost anything SDL related please see my question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sdl/comments/hxvssb/sdl2_xcode_error_flock_failed_to_lock_maps_file/).

Comment: I don't know if you are still trying to set this up but, the errors don't seem to matter (I might be wrong) the only thing is apparently on macOS you need to have an event loop for windows to appear. So if you can go on and ignore the errors (I don't know why they're there but so far they haven't affected me) and keep on writing your app.

Comment: What is the event loop?